# Optimizing ListView performance with complex items

Tags: android, listview

I have a `ListView` with fairly tall and complex items but nothing too extreme. Each item is a `CardView` with a varying number of rows.

Unfortunately, it seems quite hard to make the scrolling completely smooth.

Even if the adapter's `getView()` method does pretty much nothing except returning the recycled view, there are frames above 16ms.

The slow frames have much slower draw times than other frames (such as 8ms) because the item is invalidated and drawn to cache when user scrolls to it (I assume).

I tried setting `scrolling_cache` to `false`, didn't help. Using a `RecyclerView` didn't improve the performance either.

Comment: why don't you give try on `RecyclerView`

Comment: I'll try and update the post soon.

Comment: @NJ didn't help

Comment: A recyclerview is much more efficient, advanced and flexible as the listview widget.

Comment: @LucaZiegler I doubt that it's significantly more efficient. It didn't improve perfomance in my case at all.

Comment: how many items do you have in your list?

Comment: Usually between 5 and 100.

Comment: With `RecyclerView` you can set different `ViewHolder` for each item of your list. Try splitting your list item. It would be great if I could take a look at your list item and adapter.

Comment: @ReazMurshed unfortunately I can't because the item is clickable CardView... And ListView can work with different ViewHolder types too.

Comment: Can you please let me see your code?

Comment: @ReazMurshed sorry, I can't post share the code online, but there are no surprises, just tall and complex-ish items in a ListView. Some frames are slightly above 16ms, even when getView() is instant, which will not be the case in production.

Comment: I understand. I'm writing a generic answer then..

Answer (score 0):

First of all a `ListView` should not have a complex layout. If the `ListView` item can be expanded or something like that, there are other ways to do it. You might consider using `ExpandableListView` for this purpose.

But anyway, as your list item is a complex one, I ran through a similar situation earlier and I had to make the list item layout as simple as I could. I replaced all of my `LinearLayout` with `RelativeLayout` so that it reduces the `View` hierarchy.

If your list item (i.e. `CardView`) contains any image, you might have already considered using Glide or Picasso for loading the images.

Another trick I used once was to detect the fling scroll in the `ListView` using its `onScrollListener` for a complex list item.

```
@Override
public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView absListView, int scrollState) {
    if(scrollState != SCROLL_STATE_FLING) {
        // Populate views here
    }
}
```

Avoid any database calls or loops inside your `getView` function. You might have considered them already. I'm just putting my thoughts altogether.